# Can I clone a MongoDB aggregation pipeline and aggregate some more?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a lot of processor intensive aggregation pipelines, but the only difference is actually the last few steps.

Can I clone the pipeline at a specific point and apply some more aggregation in order to save time for the redundant part?

E.g. (warning, this is made up code):

```
collection.aggregate([ // Redundant part of the pipeline
    { $match: query },
    { $project: project },
    { $unwind: unwind },
    { $match: query },
    { $project: project }
], function(err, cursor) { // Unique part of the pipelines

    cursor.aggregate([
        { $group: group1}
    ], cb1);

    cursor.aggregate([
        { $group: group2}
    ], cb2);

    cursor.aggregate([
        { $group: group3}
    ], cb3);
});
```

I prefer to clone the pipeline at a specific point in the MongoDB adapter over using a physical [temporary collection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) because this happens on every Node.js request, which can have many users at the same time, and `$out` is not actually meant for temporary storage like that.

Answer (score 0):

Redsandro,

You can accomplish what you want by creating an aggregation query for the "common" part of your aggregation queries.

You can then write the output of the "common steps" to a "new" collection using the $out. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/.

Once that is done, you can apply aggregation framework queries to the new created collection

Comment: I read about that before, but it sounds intensive for aggregations that occur on every request. (I'll add the request thing to the question to be more specific.) We would need to create and remove random collections so as not to contaminate one requests' temp collection with the other. I guess this saves memory but wastes time, unless the queries are huge. Is there data or documentation about overhead for this? E.g. when does this start to become feasible?